# Encode only accented characters in an HTML string

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, html-entities

I have the following function that accepts an HTML string, for example `"<p>áêö</p>"`:

```
public string EncodeString(string input)
{
    // ...
    return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input);
}
```

I'd like to modify that function to output the same string, but with the accented characters as HTML entities. Using `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()` encodes the entire string, including the HTML tags. I'd like to preserve the HTML tags if possible, since the string is parsed and rendered elsewhere in the application. Is this something that is better solved with a regex?

Comment: Why do you want to encode unicode characters? Just use `utf-8` as your web encoding (everywhere), then browsers happily displays unicode strings.

Comment: `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input).Replace( '&lt;','<').Replace( '&gt;','>');`

Comment: @PoulBak As much as this is the ideal solution I do not currently have control of where the input strings come from (they are passed as HTML strings already) and what application renders them (best I can say is it is *not* a modern browser)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possibly the oddest solution, but...

```
public static string EncodeString(string input)
{
    string startTag = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(">") + 1);
    string endTag = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("</"), startTag.Length + 1);
    input = input.Substring(startTag.Length, input.Length - endTag.Length - startTag.Length);
    return startTag + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input) + endTag;
}
```

Comment: This won't work with nested tags, like `<p>áê<i>áê</i></p>`.

Comment: @PoulBak true, didn't think about that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) to replace the content of an html element:

```
public static async Task<string> EncodeString(string input)
{
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
    var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(input));
    var pElement = document.QuerySelector("p");
    pElement.TextContent = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(pElement.TextContent);
    return pItem.ToHtml();
}
```

See it in action here: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XgTRTQ)

---

For more general situations where you have nested elements, here's the adapted code:

```
public static async Task<string> EncodeString(string input)
{
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
    var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(input));
    return await EncodeString(document.Body.FirstChild);
}

private static async Task<string> EncodeString(INode content)
{
    foreach(var node in content.ChildNodes)
    {
        node.NodeValue = node.NodeType == NodeType.Text ?
            System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(node.NodeValue) :
            await EncodeString(node);
    }
    return content.ToHtml();
}
```

Comment: This won't work with nested tags, like `<p>áê<i>áê</i></p>`.

Comment: It's not perfect, but I expanded my answer.